# Displaying text in input field when a button is clicked(php/html)

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

I need some help with the following; I want to display a newly generated password(function in php)when the button "gww" is clicked inside another input field. Could someone shed some light?

```
<td><input type="button" value="Generate" name="gww"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="ww"></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function password()
{
var elem = document.getElementById("ww");
elem.value = "<? echo random_Password(); ?>";
}
</script>

function random_Password($length = 8)
{
//empty password string
$password = "";


//Possible characters
$karakters = "123456789abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz";

$maxlength = strlen($karakters);
if($length > $maxlength)
{
    $length = $maxlength;
}
$i = 0;
while($i < $length)
{
    $char = substr($karakters, mt_rand(0, $maxlength-1), 1);
    if(!strstr($password, $char))
    {
        $password .= $char;
        $i++;
    }
}
return $password;
}
```

Comment: then go for it what is your problem

Comment: You cannot mix PHP and HTML/Javascript like this. PHP is run server side, HTML/Javascript client side. To get a PHP-generated password in HTML/Javascript you'll need a technology like AJAX.

Comment: It is not working. It's currently always displaying the password, not when I click the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want a new password to be shown whenever you click the button. You have to use AJAX for this.

So you have your javascript function:

```
function generatePassword()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
   {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.document.getElementById("ww").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.example.com/generatepassword.php",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Your HTML should be

```
<input type="button" value="Generate password" onClick="generatePassword()">
```

generatePassword.php:

```
<?php
echo random_Password();

function random_Password($length = 8)
{
  //your function here ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I was about to comment that PHP is serverside so the call to random_password happens once in the OP's posted code. Ajax seemst o be the best way to do it, or to create a Javascript function to generate a random password.

Comment: Yeah, wanted to add that, you beat me to it lol :P But then your password generation mechanism won't be secret!!!! :O

Comment: It doesn't have to be secret, not if it generates a password based on random things like browser locale + time of day, mouse movement, key's typed etc. Anyone can copy/paste the function, but they wont generate the same password twice (not in a reasonable amount of time anyway). Plus I should add, passwords being sent via Ajax (and in cleartext) are not secure. But it solves the OP's problem and is reasonably usable. To get true security you would want encryption to happen at the client and server before anything is sent over the wires.

Comment: And if you store your passwords in a secure way (some hashes plus unique salts) it won't matter how passwords are being generated.

Comment: I am still stuck, got the following code but it's still not working..                                                       <script type="text/javascript">
function generate_Password()
{
 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttp.open("GET", "/gpass.php");
 xmlHttp.send(null);

 updateText(xmlHttp.responseText);
}

function updateText(text)
{
 var elem = document.getElementById("ww");
 elem.value = text;
}

</script>

Comment: What happens if you replace `xmlHttp.open("GET", "/gpass.php"); ` with `xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://your_full_url.com/gpass.php");`

Comment: Ok I found another thing that may be the problem: xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://your_full_url.com/gpass.php", true); ` notice the third argument I added. This tells the xmlHttp to do the request asynchronously. Do you have something like Firefox's plugin.. what's the name...

Comment: Hmm..isn't working either and I don't have any knowledge of AJAX so I am really stuck here :/

Comment: What is the response code of the request, open firefox, go to your url, press ctrl+shift+k. Press the button, and you should see an entry. If it's something else than 200 the PHP file is not okay. Otherwise there is a problem with the JavaScript. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Ajax is really simple, it is just PHP, combined with JavaScript. You just output or use the result of a PHP script in a page that's already open, using javascript. ;)

Comment: Who's instructions? Mine or @AmazingDreams? What happens when you just browse to the gpass.php file by URL in your web browser (http://yoursite/gpass.php)? Do you see a random password?

Comment: @AmazingDreams but your code isn't working either. And yes a random password does show up

Comment: Have you got `<input type="button" value="Random password" onClick="generatePassword()">` ??

Upon re-reading your question, I see you have not specified this. I'll add it to the answer, and replace the code with the code of @Husman, since that is less prone to failure.

Comment: I'll modify my code, so that the whole solution is in one place. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as is.

```
<td><input type="button" value="Generate" name="gww" onClick="generatePassword()"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="ww"></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function generatePassword()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.document.getElementById("ww").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gpass.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I take it you already have gpass.php as:

```
<?php
echo random_Password();

function random_Password($length = 8)
{
  //your function here ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you open up your browser and just browse to your gpass.php file by url. What happens? what do you see on your screen?

Comment: The onClick is in an annoyingly weird place :P

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but I managed to fix it! You guys were talking about a continueing renewing generated password but my goal was to only generate once which luckily works now thanks to your help @Husman & AmazingDreams =D

Comment: No worries Fliptab. Fixed the onclick, not that it matters anymore @AmazingDreams

Answer (score 0):

PHP is serverside, so your call to

```
echo random_Password();
```

only happens on page load, and it happens once. Create the function in javascript and have an onClick attribute for the button. Or use Ajax as mentioned by someone else in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that the following code only runs once:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ww");
elem.value = "<? echo random_Password(); ?>";
```

So, suppose your `random_Password()` function (totally implausibly) returned the value ***12345678***, this value is held until the page is manually refreshed. With out a refresh, clicking the **GWW** button will set the **WW** field to ***12345678*** every time.

You have a few different options here (easiest to hardest):

1. Have the **GWW** button perform a full-page refresh when clicked. **Not** desirable.
2. Convert your random_Password() function into JavaScript code and execute it in the client. Very straightforward, but it reveals to hackers how passwords are being generated, and as such is not **secure**.
3. Use **AJAX**. Move your `random_Password()` function into it's own file, `random_password.php` and load the "page" (i.e. an 8-character string) into the text field's `val`.

I would opt for **Option 3** in 99% of cases. Tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Hope that helps :)